# How do I create randomized word lists that are dependent on a master list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

**I am using excel for Mac 2011**

For a linguistics project I want to do the following. I will have a word-list like this (in reality it will be much bigger):

Master List:

1. Bag
2. Leg
3. Magnet
4. Apple
5. Gum

First, I copy and paste the words to a new sheet. Then, I create random numbers (using RAND) in an adjacent column. To get a randomized list, I use SORT, to sort the word list by the value of the randomly created numbers.

1. Bag     .011234123
2. Leg     .001324234
3. Magnet  .01324243
4. Apple   .013245588
5. Gum     .0123412341

Sort By NUMBERS COLUMN

THIS GETS ME:::

Randomization 1:

5. Gum
6. Magnet
7. Apple
8. Bag
9. Let

I will have several randomizations. Suppose I want to change a word. Is there a way to make the randomization depend on the master list? That is, if I make a change to the master list (change a word), is there a way for these changes to also be carried out on my randomization?

Comment: The answer is going to depend on how you accomplish your random word selection. Please share with us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I randomize this list by copying the words onto a new sheet. Then, I use RAND to create random numbers in a column adjacent to the word list:

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You could sort your master list by the random number and then use `INDEX()`.

Comment: @Kyle could you elaborate?

Comment: Have a master list of words and make your word changes there.  The randomized lists would be cell references that point to the master list.  Then just rearrange the cell references.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest a solution using a combination of RAND(), RANK() and VLOOKUP() :

First, create your master list :

[image]

Then add a column which generates a random number using `RAND()` :

[image]

Then, a column which will use RANK() to rank those random numbers : `=RANK(E2,E:E)`

[image]

Finally, use ROW() and VLOOKUP() to return the sorted ranks : `=VLOOKUP(ROW()-1,C:D,2,0)`

[image]

Any words you add to the master list will cause each RAND() to recalculate, which will then change the ranking, essentially creating a newly randomized order.

[image]

Repeat this three times for the three randomized lists you require.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting such a detailed explanation. I was able to follow your steps except for the last one. I created RAND 2 and RANK 2. However, when I use vlookup to create ORDER 2, the column is identical to ORDER 1. I tried messing around with the arguments, but can't figure it out.

Comment: I have made a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qwpK1-dsd1amOwEelMkV4WSL3jz76V8pBbZF2zk-0OI/edit?usp=sharing) here so you can take a look and download.

Comment: Excellent. I was able to figure it out with your spreadsheet :)

Comment: 2 more follow up questions:

Comment: a) Is there a way to stop the lists from recalculating each time. I know this happens because RAND is a volatile function. One solution I can think if is... perhaps I could copy and paste the values generated by RAND into a new column use it to replace the RAND column. This way, rank will always be based on these values which won't change. Trying to think of a better way to do this.

Comment: b) Now that I have my randomized lists. I want to add some "dummy words", i.e 3 words at the beginning of the list and 3 words at the end of the list. These words help prevent subjects, who I will record reading the words,  from having weird list-reading intonation. On a separate sheet, I have been trying to use index() to refer to the randomized list, and insert this randomized list into blank cells with three dummy words at the top and three dummy words at the bottom. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: a) You can [disable automatic recalculation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4). You will then have to hit the `F9` key to manually recalculate RAND()

Comment: b) Actually, I don't think you need to create any formulas for these, since their position and values are fixed, just add three rows to the top and bottom, and copy those words there :)

Comment: Follow up on b: When I add three new rows of dummy words to the top, the bottom three words appear as #N/A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29236/discussion-between-max-carey-and-teikjoon).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is on Sheet1 starting at A1, and sorted by column B, which is the random number, put this formula starting at row 1, and autofill down:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$6,ROW())
```

It simply uses `ROW()` to increment the `row_num` argument of `INDEX()` as it is filled down.

Or, if you don't want to sort, try this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$6,MATCH(LARGE(Sheet1!B$1:B$6,ROW()),Sheet1!B$1:B$6,0))
```

This one is a bit more fun. Again using `ROW()` to increment automatically, it uses `LARGE()` to find the next largest random number, then `INDEX/MATCH` to return the word at that position.

Bear in mind that `RAND()` is volatile, meaning it will recalculate itself every time your worksheet is calculated. I recommend using manual calculation if you're going to use this method.

Comment: Hello Kyle. Thanks for elaborating. I appreciate it as I do not have much programming experience with excel. Regarding the first equation, I would like the master list to always be in the same order and have 3 different randomizations that are all dependent on the master list. I'm not sure I can o this with index.

Comment: @MaxCarey That's what the second formula is for. You can make three columns of `RAND()` to make your three randomizations, then use that formula three times, referencing a different random column each time. Just change the `B$1:B$6` reference in both places. @teikjoon's answer looks like it does the same thing, with a shorter formula at the expense of needing more helper columns.